# WolframClient in Python: how to convert the output of wolframclient.evaluate into a sympy expression?

Tags: python, sympy, wolfram-mathematica, symbols, wolfram-language

I'm using wolframclient in Python and at certain point of my computation I have an output like the following

```
(Plus[-9, Times[2, Power[Global`y, 4]]], Plus[Times[3, Global`x], Times[-2, Power[Global`y, 3]]])
```

Now I need to convert this output into sympy format, something like

```py
    [-9 + 2*y**4, 3*x - 2*y**3]
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

The mathematica parser doesn't seem to like the tuple, so if you can get the two parts separate and replace the "Global`" with a null string, it can work:

```
>>> a = 'Plus[-9, Times[2, Power[Global`y, 4]]]'
>>> b = 'Plus[Times[3, Global`x], Times[-2, Power[Global`y, 3]]]'
>>> from sympy.parsing.mathematica import parse_mathematica as p # in current dev version?
>>> [p(i.replace('Global`','')) for i in (a,b)]
[2*y**4 - 9, 3*x - 2*y**3]
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your commands but I get the following error message: `ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_mathematica' from 'sympy.parsing.mathematica' (/Users/luca/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/parsing/mathematica.py)`

Whereas using ``from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica as p`` I got ``ValueError: 'Plus' is out of the whitelist.``

Sorry, it's probably my fault, I'm not an expert...

Comment: You will need the dev version which you can download from https://github.com/sympy/sympy

Comment: Oh - thanks, in the meantime I think I've solved my problem in another way.

I'll explain it a bit in the following. 
Using `ToString[expr, FortranForm]` in Mathematica, you can get a Python list of the expressions involved, something like `['2*y**4 - 9', '3*x - 2*y**3']` (i.e. a Python list of strings). 
Then, I simply call `sympify()` from sympy to convert a string in a simpy expression.